# VB6: Why most people use ADODB over ADODC?

Tags: vb6

I saw that most of the time researching about database I notice that most people use ADODB in connecting to database. What my teacher use is that she uses ADODC in connecting to database.

I find it frustrating to search some examples about ADODC and how to use it because most people use ADODB.

Why do they prefer ADODB than ADODC?

What happen if they use ADODC than ADODB?

Comment: The ADO Data Control is a simple datasource useful in simple programs and thus for teaching.  It has a big brother the DataEnvironment that is far more flexible.  Raw ADO programming (copy/paste coders call this "ADODB") became popular because of a plethora of classic ASP VBScript examples they could copy and paste.  There is really nothing more to it, data binding just isn't something they understand so they cling to the QBasic model of coding they can cope with better.

Comment: ADODB is the direct data access, while ADODC is a 'wrapper' (with some bugs) of ADODB, therefore ADODB is the best way to data access.

Comment: I see thanks. @GiorgioBrausi